# Placing a Div between two Images inside a table cell

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm creating a League table and I want to include each team's logo on the left and right of each result (example below).

I've been trying using float:right and left but it's not working as intended.

HTML:

```
<table border=2> 
    <tr>
      <th>Local Team</th>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Away Team</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Team 1</td>
      <td><img class="photoL" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cup/154/football-shield-club-sport-512.png" alt="" /><div class="result">0 - 0 </div><img class="photoR" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cup/154/football-shield-club-sport-512.png" alt="" /></td>
      <td>Team 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.photoL {
  max-width: 66px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important;
}

.photoR {
  max-width: 66px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important;
}

.result {
}
```

The result I'm looking for would be: `[IMG1] 0 - 0 [IMG2]` all in the same line inside the `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Remove floats, just replace the "results" DIV with a SPAN to make those items inline with images.

```
.photoL {
max-width: 66px;
height: 40px;

}

.photoR {
max-width: 66px;
height: 40px;

}

.result {
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
} 

img{
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

here is html:

```
<table border=2> 
  <tr>
    <th>Local Team</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Away Team</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Team 1</td>
    <td><img class="photoL" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cup/154/football-shield-club-sport-512.png" alt="" />
<span class="result">0 - 0 </span><img class="photoR" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cup/154/football-shield-club-sport-512.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td>Team 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is close but it's not centered vertically, vertical-align is not working there either...

Comment: You didn't ask for it to be centered vertically.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like Flex to achieve this.
Learn more about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can modify the code below to your liking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table{
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

tr > th {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 33.33%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

<p>The "flex-direction: row-reverse;" stacks the flex items horizontally (but from right to left):</p>

<table>
<tr class="flex-container">
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>  
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!